# Error in Manifest while using GCM for push Notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have started working on GCM Notification 
after a lot of goggling i checked out code through which i can get registration id from GCM Server so i used

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

final String regId= GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, "338056690461");
}
else{
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}

  But When i run My Application i get error on   `CheckMAnifest()`
```

this means i have   error in my manifest but accordint to me my manifest is correct please have alook to my    Exception as well as manifest

Exception it gives

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission PushNotification.Pop.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

and manifest i have used is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="PushNotification.Pop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="PushNotification.Pop.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="PushNotification.Pop.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="PushNotification.Pop" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

       <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please suggest me where i am going wrong your help would be greatfull
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ,which emulator is you are using mean google api or simple

Comment: i am using samsung galaxy pop OS (2.2.1) @Bhupendrasinh
i am using google API

Comment: One more question have you configured google account on that device ??

Comment: @Bhupendrasinh yes i have configured google account but the google should be the same of which i am sending Sender_ID

Comment: @Bhupendrasinh When i run may demo app it says
[2013-05-10 12:36:11 - PushNotification] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
[2013-05-10 12:36:11 - PushNotification] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-05-10 12:36:11 - PushNotification] Launch canceled!

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion="24"`?

Comment: @LalitPoptani Big Deal i have changed it to 8 Still same problem

Comment: @raghavchopra post your updated Manifest file then.

Comment: @LalitPoptani  Updated the Latest manifest Please check , Thanks !

Comment: @raghav solved the problem ??

Comment: @Bhupendrasinh Well i copied the same manifest but error persiist let me know one thing in 
<permission
        android:name="indieswebs.magento.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
We need to edit our package name i guess

Comment: yes sry change it to your package name

Comment: @Bhupendrasinh Sorry same error have neva think about manifest for so long before

Comment: @LalitPoptani i Have also tried it on 2.3.1 it is giving same manifest  error ? Confused ?

Comment: @raghavchopra got the solution or not i have update my ans

Answer (score 0):

try to copy and paste this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="PushNotification.Pop"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>


    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

   <uses-permission android:name="PushNotification.Pop.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 


     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 


     <permission
        android:name="indieswebs.magento.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />  

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                >

        <activity android:name="PushNotification.Pop.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name_title"
                  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="PushNotification.Pop" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="PushNotification.Pop.GCMIntentService" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

or
I got answer for this issue. Just delete "gen"folder . It build automatically. Application will work fine.

Comment: It is giving the same problem

Comment: i dont know whats the proble, it is all correct hard to find error @bhupendra

Comment: yes!!! but i think problem is with your activity or with your package name do check that

Comment: Already checked that package name is same as it is given any Resolve ?